# How to migrate codable data schemas in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm curious, are there any best practices that are generally recognised as good ways to migrate Codable data across schema changes in Swift?

For instance, I might have:

```swift
struct RecordV1: Codable {
    var name: String
}

struct RecordV2: Codable {
    var firstName: String   // Renamed old name field
    var lastName: String    // Added this field
}
```

I want to be able to load something that was saved as RecordV1 into RecordV2.

I would like to implement my data structures in such a way that what is stored has a version number embedded in it so that in the future, when loading the data, at some future date when newer versions of code are working with more recent versions of data, some mechanism would have the chance to migrate the old data into the most recent schema. I want the solution to be fairly elegant and to not involve lots of retyping of boilerplate code. The Swiftier the better!

Answer (score 0):

I have searched high and low, but I haven't found any solutions for this discussed anywhere. Below, is the best solution I've been able to think of. I would love it if people could suggest alternatives (especially using Combine, or using protocols and generics in better ways).

Pardon the length of this post. I'll break it down into parts, but paste them all into a Swift Playground, and it should work.

The first part is defining a protocol for migratable structures, defining a method to identify the version of the MigratableData, and defining an initializer for importing data from a structure saved by the previous version. There's also an `init(from: withVersion: using:)` that crawls up the chain of migrations and decodes the data at the right version, then migrates the structure forward to the current version.

I implemented the `init(from: withVersion: using:)` method as a default protocol implementation. I am particularly concerned by [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/swift-why-you-should-avoid-using-default-implementations-in-protocols-eeffddbed46d) suggesting this is a bad idea. I'd love to hear how to avoid that problem.

```swift
import Foundation

protocol MigratableData: Codable {
    associatedtype PrevMD: MigratableData               // so we can refer to the previous MigratableData type being migrated from
    associatedtype CodingKeyEnum: CodingKey             // needed only for MDWrapper below

    static func getDataVersion() -> Int                 // basically an associated constant
    init(from: PrevMD)
    init(from: Data, withVersion dataVersion: Int, using: JSONDecoder) throws  // JSONDecode instead of decoder because .decode is not part of Decoder
}

extension MigratableData {
    // default implementation of init(from: withVersion: using:)
    init(from data: Data, withVersion dataVersion: Int, using decoder: JSONDecoder) throws {
        if Self.getDataVersion() == dataVersion {
            self = try decoder.decode(Self.self, from: data)
        } else if Self.getDataVersion() > dataVersion {
            self.init(from: try PrevMD(from: data, withVersion: dataVersion, using: decoder))
        } else {
            fatalError("Data is too new!")
        }
    }
}
```

Once we have that protocol, it's just a matter of defining some structures and wiring up the connections between them - implicitly using version numbers and `init(from:)`:

```swift
struct RecordV1: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey { case name }  // needed only for MDWrapper below

    var name: String
}

struct RecordV2: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey { case firstName, lastName }   // needed only for MDWrapper below

    var firstName: String   // Renamed old name field
    var lastName: String    // Added this field
}

extension RecordV1: MigratableData {
    typealias CodingKeyEnum = CodingKeys
    static func getDataVersion() -> Int { 1 }

    // We set up an "upgrade circularity" but it's safe and never gets invoked.
    init(from oldRecord: RecordV1) {
        fatalError("This should not be called")
    }
}

extension RecordV2: MigratableData {
    typealias CodingKeyEnum = CodingKeys
    static func getDataVersion() -> Int { 2 }
    
    init(from oldRecord: RecordV1) {
        self.firstName = oldRecord.name     // We do a key migration here
        self.lastName = "?"    // Since we have no way of generating anything
    }
}
```

And to use it, and prove it works, we can do the following:

```swift
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

// creating test data
let recordV1 = RecordV1(name: "John")
let recordV2 = RecordV2(firstName: "Johnny", lastName: "AppleSeed")

// converting it to Data that would be stored somewhere
let dataV1 = try encoder.encode(recordV1)
let dataV2 = try encoder.encode(recordV2)

// you can view as strings while debugging
let stringV1 = String(data: dataV1, encoding: .utf8)
let stringV2 = String(data: dataV2, encoding: .utf8)

// loading back from the data stores, migrating if needed.
let recordV1FromV1 = try RecordV1(from: dataV1, withVersion: 1, using: decoder)
let recordV2FromV1 = try RecordV2(from: dataV1, withVersion: 1, using: decoder)

let recordV2FromV2 = try RecordV2(from: dataV2, withVersion: 2, using: decoder)
```

So all warts aside, the above works the way I want. I just don't like that I have to keep track of the version that's being migrated from (the `withVersion:` parameter) when loading. Ideally, the version number should be part of the data that's saved, so that it can be automatically read and applied.

My best solution for that, so far, is to wrap the Data structures in a generic called MDWrapper:

```swift
// MDWrapper is short for MigratableDataWrapper
//
// It encapsulates the data and the version into one object that can be
// easily encoded/decoded with automatic migration of data schema from
// older versions, using the init(from: oldVersionData) initializers
// that are defined for each distinct MigratedData type.
struct MDWrapper<D: MigratableData> {
    var dataVersion: Int
    var data: D
    var stringData = ""     // Not ever set, read, or saved, but used as a placeholder for encode/decode
    
    init(data: D) {
        self.data = data
        self.dataVersion = D.getDataVersion()
    }
}

extension MDWrapper : Codable {
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey { case stringData, dataVersion }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(dataVersion, forKey: .dataVersion)
        
        // Here we encode the wrapped data into JSON Data, then hide it's
        // structure by encoding that data into a base64 string that's
        // fed into our wrapped data representation, and spit it out
        // in the stringData coding key. We never actually write out
        // a data field
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(data)
        let base64data = jsonData.base64EncodedString()
        
        try container.encode(base64data, forKey: .stringData)
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        dataVersion = D.getDataVersion()

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let version = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .dataVersion)
        let base64data = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .stringData)

        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        data = try D.init(from: base64data, withVersion: version, using: jsonDecoder)
    }
}
```

I had to do all sort of jumping through hoops to get that to work. Again, constructive criticism would be most welcome. Here are some more tests to prove this works, and as you can see the manual version numbers have gone away:

```swift
// created wrapped versions of the test data above
let recordV1Wrapper = MDWrapper<RecordV1>(data: recordV1)
let recordV2Wrapper = MDWrapper<RecordV2>(data: recordV2)

// creating Data that can be stored from the wrapped versions
let wrappedDataV1 = try encoder.encode(recordV1Wrapper)
let wrappedDataV2 = try encoder.encode(recordV2Wrapper)

// string for debug viewing
let wrappedStringV1 = String(data: wrappedDataV1, encoding: .utf8)
let wrappedStringV2 = String(data: wrappedDataV2, encoding: .utf8)

// loading back from the data stores, migrating if needed.
let rebuiltV1WrapperFromV1Data = try decoder.decode(MDWrapper<RecordV1>.self, from: wrappedDataV1)
let rebuiltV2WrapperFromV1Data = try decoder.decode(MDWrapper<RecordV2>.self, from: wrappedDataV1)

let rebuiltV2WrapperFromV2Data = try decoder.decode(MDWrapper<RecordV2>.self, from: wrappedDataV2)

// isolating the parts we actually need so we can discard the wrappers
let rebuiltV1FromV1 = rebuiltV1WrapperFromV1Data.data
let rebuiltV2FromV1 = rebuiltV2WrapperFromV1Data.data

let rebuiltV2FromV2 = rebuiltV2WrapperFromV2Data.data
```

Comment: You can do it much simpler, IMHO. You can [test whether a coding key exists](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer/contains(_:)), so you simply have a `Record: Codable` and when decoding it, check whether the legacy key exists. If so, load it and split it. Add a `version`/`format` key to the new format so that in the future, you can load that key first and then decide on how to decode the record.